# How to add desired Text to jQuery pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-pagination

I want to add custom text in front of jQuery pagination plugin

we got like following in JQuery pagination plugin

```
  |<    <  1/23   >  >|
```

I want to add text before it like following:

```
   Page: |<    <  1/23   >  >|
```

I want like second format. How can I get it?
Anybody know how to get the "div" id in that control too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination has been packed, so I went to download the unpacked version at http://rohitsengar.cueblocks.net/jquery-pagination-plugin/.

Scroll to the **bottom** of the script and look for:

```
$(".paginator").html(style);
```

and change it to:

```
$(".paginator").html('<span>Page: </span>' + style);
```

Comment: I use this one http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination and   I can't find the words you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Samuel, it work with   initPaginator();
$('.paginator').prepend('<span>Page: </span>'); but if navigate , the text disappear. so How can I fix that?

Comment: that's replace all navigation part.

Comment: When I add this line $(".paginator").html('<span>Page: </span>' + style);
it shows 2 lines of Page: |<    <  1/23   >  >|
and at second page "Page:" is missed and it shows 2 lines of |<    <  1/23   >  >|

Comment: Thanks Samuel , Now I got it! I use this                           .paginator:before{ content:"Page";font-family:@Arial;font-size:13px;}
 <!--[if lte IE ]>
  div.paginator:before{ content:"Page";font-family:@Arial;font-size:13px;}
 <![endif]-->

Comment: :before pseudo isn't support for IE7 so I have to use these code for IE7      <div id="divpage" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;position:absolute;top:580px;left:450px;display:none;">Page</div>
     <script>
      $(".paginator").add("divpage");
     </script>